# What formula to give small values more weight?

Tags: curves

I have the following image which contain images ordered and scaled according a *rank* value, the biggest having a *rank* of 1 and the smallest a *rank* of 77:

[image]

I would like to give smaller *ranks* more 'weight', so they become a little bigger.

The logarithm seems quite interesting but the problem is that I don't know how to 'contain' it in a 0.0 to 1.0 space:

[image]

Do you know what formula could be used to give smaller values more weight ?

Comment: Your purpose being to shift values ranging $1$ thru $77$ to values ranging $0$ thru $1$??? If yes, then how about $\frac{\log(x)}{\log(77)}$? Or $\sqrt{\frac{x}{77}}$?

Comment: @barakmanos : works great, thank you ! feel free to post an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: You're welcome. Added that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your purpose is to shift the values from $[1,77]$ to $[0,1]$ while increasing the relative weights of the smaller ones comparing with the larger ones, then you can try either one of the following options:

- $\dfrac{\log(x)}{\log(77)}$
- $\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{77}}$